Installing ceiling fan box under slightly off center joist
I am attempting to put a ceiling fan box centered above a kitchen island to mount a <20 lb ceiling fan and have run into a minor issue.
There was a non-ceiling-fan rated box (standard 4' x 1 1/2" octagon) in this location.  The distance to the bottom of the joist is 2" so a 1/2" plywood spacer the width of the joist was used to mount the 1 1/2" box (see figure).  The real problem is that the ceiling joist in this location is slightly off center (1/4 - 1/2") and moving the fan location off center from the island would be pretty obvious as the island is small and the ceiling is not high.

I am trying to figure out a way to appropriately mount a box centered on the island.  I do not have access to the space from above and would really like to avoid ripping open the ceiling.  A couple thoughts/questions:

The L shaped mounts don't seem to work here since as far as I can tell they are centered on the joist and don't accommodate the 2" space from the bottom of the joist to the ceiling.  Or are there versions of these that have a small amount of leeway in where the screws go into the joist and have larger spacing?

Can I use a round ceiling box and screw into the 2 holes that are both off center of the joist on the same side as shown here (see arrows in image below) or do I need to have 4 screws?  If I use a 1 1/2" box, is the use of a plywood spacer between the joist and box ok so long as the screws go fully through the plywood and into the joist?



Thanks in advance.

Yeah, that will probably work if you can get screws into the joist solidly. You also might be able to use something like one of these: https://www.amazon.com/54151CFB-BHL-OW-Pre-Galvanized-Octagon-Ceiling-Knockouts/dp/B000LNPU9W

You can see half an inch of offset? Impressive.

@isherwood I was gonna ask if the OP took a plumb bob and determined that the box wasn't centered.

You must use the spacer.  When you tighten the fan's bracket it must mate with the box not the ceiling.  Otherwise vibrations and any wobbling will be transmitted to the drywall. The spacer must mate well with the joist and with the box.   Use screws long enough to go through the spacer and at least another inch into the joist. Overdrill the spacer so the screws turn freely in them.
It looks to me like with the four holes that you highlighted, if you rotate the box while it's centered in the hole, you can arrange for two of them to be centered on the joist.  They don't have to be dead center.  Then, if any other holes align with the joist even if they are not centered, use those too.

The center of the box is on the joist, so you can use any pair of opposite holes if you rotate the box apropriately.
I would use the two holes that are closest to the flat parts. this will remove the lever effect you get if you use off-center screw holes.  which hole you use will not change hos the joist sees the load

Hi.  Thanks for the answer.  The issue is that to keep the fan centered on the island, the box will not be centered on the joist.  From your answer, it sounds like it would be a problem to use the 2 off center holes.  A couple additional questions:  1)  Is mounting with 2 screws if they are opposite from one another enough?  and 2) Is it OK to use the 1/2" plywood spacer or do I need to find a 2" ceiling fan box?

If the screws get a firm hold on the joist it is enougha spacer is ok, but use longer screws so they can hold on the joist and not just the spacer.
